How to implement an API according to existing schema in Open API format
So I got handled a API scheme. It looks something like this:
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Example API",
    "version": "3.1.0"
  },

I don't want to attach all the scheme, but it is a typical OPEN API scheme. With things like paths and its get and post.
What I'm missing here is what is the typical way of creating your API according to this scheme.
I mean, I cannot just read through the scheme and create endpoints according to that (I guess)?
It looks to me like there should be some mechanism to connect this json-scheme with your endpoints?
I need to create a NodeJS API which implements endpoints according to the scheme.
Is there any resource I could read about that explains the connection between an existing OPEN API-scheme and the actual API you build?

Sounds like you are looking for something like this to generate an api from a spec
